# Finding the first empty row in Excel with VBA occasionally causes skipped rows

Tags: excel, vba

When utilizing this function, every so often it seems to skip a few lines and writes to line 12 instead of line 9, even though the contents of those cells are empty. Any thoughts?

```
Function firstBlankRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
     firstBlankRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer the `ws` in the function:

```
Function firstBlankRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
     firstBlankRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End Function
```

Otherwise it takes either the `ActiveSheet` or the sheet where the code is.

Comment: Gah! How careless of me!

Comment: Great catch, by the way. Thank you! (I will best answer this once it allows me to in 11 minutes :-) )

Comment: @eGeekster - welcome. Not referring the correct worksheet causes quite a lot of problems with VBA. Btw, this is one of the most robust functions in VBA I am using, making the column a variable one - `lastRow()` - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/LastThings.vb

Comment: Appreciate the additional info, I have already noticed a number of ways to improve my code. The project I'm currently undertaking requires a deeper understanding of VB that I'm stumbling through. At this point, I'm searching for a method similar to PHP's include/require. Any suggestions?

Comment: @eGeekster - in general, you may add some additional libraries. But it depends on the context and what exactly is needed.